# Create a CAD model from python surface plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, cad

I am trying to create lenses with a specific geometry. In Python, I have calculated and plotted their shape as a surface plot:

[image: Surface Plot of Lens Geometry]

In order to actually build these models, I need to convert this to a CAD-compatible file format. As I do not have any experience with CAD software, I would like to know if there is any way to convert python surface plota to CAD file formats directly. I'd really appreciate your help!

Comment: Matplotlib is a 2D plotting library. Its 3D capability comes from projecting into 2D space. The surface plot itself is therefore completely useless for further 3D processing.

What you need in a CAD file is the data itself. So if your data is in the format of a numpy array, the question needs to be how to convert this data to a CAD format. Since there are a couple of CAD formats around, there is no definite solution to this question.

Comment: Remember that Stackoverflow is about programming. However, if you can specify a target CAD format and provide details, including the code that you have tried for conversion, you may find help here.

Comment: Assuming axial symmetry, I would recommend creating a surface of revolution in IGES or STEP.  You'll only need to accurately compute a curve to be swept around the axis of symmetry.  The curve should be a b-spline fit to your data.  You can import IGES or STEP into most (all?) CAD packages.

Answer (score 0):

Since your surface seems to be an output of some of your code, I guess there is ne easy equation to put it into a parametric model as expected in CAD model formats `(.stp, .igs)`
However you can target a mesh format `(.stl, .ply)` used for instance in 3D printing

the difference is:

- the CAD format expects known primitives (such as lines, arcs, b-spline, ...)
- the mesh formats only store points and polygons (usally triangles) so you are completely free on the placement of your vertices

There is good python modules to write mesh formats:

- [plyfile](https://github.com/dranjan/python-plyfile)  the ply file format gives you a great flexibility on what you put in your vertices
- [numpy-stl](https://github.com/WoLpH/numpy-stl)  the stl file format is the universal solution for 3D printing

In order to use any of these formats, you will have to generate a list of triangles from your points (it's just a matrix so it will be easy):

```py
n = ... # size of your square matrix
triangles = []
for x in range(n):
    for y in range(n):
        triangles.append((x, x+1, x+n))
        triangles.append((x+1, x+1+n, x+n))
```

If you want to take advantage of the axial symetry by generating a revolution surface from a profile, or if you want to process your lense mesh in any way before exporting, you can take a look at [pymadcad](https://github.com/jimy-byerley/pymadcad), [pymesh](https://pymesh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), [trimesh](https://trimsh.org/)

Comment: Shoudln't there be a `y` in the construction of `triangles`?